# Adobe Flash Player fullscreen bug

Tags: video, flash, youtube, fullscreen

For a few days I've been experiencing a really strange behaviour when watching YouTube videos in fullscreen. It looks like this:

[image: Flash Player Fullscreen Bug]

As you can see, the video stays the same size as it had in embedded mode. It just moved to the top left corner and the space was filled with black.

I'd be glad for some help, for this is really annoying.

PS: Raring x64, Browser: Chromium v 30.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Fixed" it by switching to Google Chrome, which uses Pepper Flash. No problems since then.